# How to solve this triple integral on $[-1,1]^3$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to use this in a Gaus-Ostragradski problem, but I am at a loss as to how to solve this:

$$ \iiint_{[-1,1]^3}\frac{4}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}dxdydz$$

I am told this am be done using spherical coordinates, but am not completely sure as to how. This is what I would traditionally do, but I am not sure which intervals these components $r, \varphi, \theta$ range in. Usually it is $r\in (0,1), \varphi \in (0,2\pi), \theta \in (0,\pi).$ But that would make a sphere, which this is not, but a cube of sorts. What are the intervals of the components?

$$x=r\cos\varphi\sin \theta , y= r\sin\varphi \sin \theta, z=r\cos \theta \\ g(r,\varphi,\theta)\mapsto(x,y,z);J_g=r^2\sin\theta.$$

Comment: Why can't you change to spherical coordinates?

Comment: Hey, check it out, I updated my struggles! :)

Comment: Mathematica says
\begin{equation}
\int_{[-1,1]}\; \frac{16}{x}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2+x^2}}\right)\,dx\,
\end{equation}

Comment: Your integral is blatantly divergent if $\iiint$ has to be intended as a usual Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Yep:
\begin{equation}
\int_\varphi^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^\pi\int_{r=0}^{R(\varphi,\theta)}\frac{4}{r^3}r^2dr\sin(\theta)d\theta d\varphi
\end{equation}
for some appropriate $R(\varphi,\theta)$. So this seems to be divergent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function to be integrated is not limited in $[-1,1]^3$, thus this is an improper integral.

We use spherical coordinates:

${z = \rho sin(\phi)\\
x = \rho cos(\phi) sin(\theta)\\
y = \rho cos(\phi) cos(\theta)}$

${f(\rho, \theta, \phi) = {4\over \rho^3}}$

${\lim_{\rho -> 0^+} {4\over\rho^3} = +\infty. }$

The integral diverges to $+\infty$, as a matter of fact you can underestimate it with the integral on the sphere of radius 1.

Comment: You forgot the contribute given by the Jacobian, but both $\frac{1}{\rho^2}$ and $\frac{1}{\rho}$ are still non-integrable in a right neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: To compute a limit, I don't need the Jacobian.

Comment: That is false. By your way, you get that $$\iiint_{(-1,1)^3} \frac{d\mu}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ is divergent, but it isn't.

Comment: Problem is that the correct limit to compute is the one with the Jacobian contribution considered. Clearly you can compute the limit without the Jacobian but that limit has no relationship with the problem

Comment: By your reasoning $$\begin{align}
+\infty = \lim_{||(x,y,z)||->0^+} {1\over{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \\ \lim_{\rho->0^+} {\rho^2 cos(\theta) \over \rho^2} = \\ \lim_{\rho->0^+} {cos(\theta)} \text{ where } \theta \in [0,2pi] \\ \text{so } \lim_{\rho->0^+} {cos(\theta)} \text{ doesn't exist.}\\ \text{while} \lim_{||(x,y,z)||->0^+} {1\over{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \\ \lim_{\rho->0^+} {1 \over \rho^2} = +\infty\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So to compute a limit in polar coordinates I don't have to use the Jacobian. This, clearly, does NOT imply that: $$\begin{align} \\ \iiint_{(-1,1)^3} {1\over{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \\ \end{align} $$ is divergent.

Comment: Furthermore: $${\begin{align} \\ \iiint_{(-1,1)^3} {1\over {\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}^\alpha} \\ \end{align} } $$ converges when $${\begin{align} \ \alpha < 3 \end{align} } $$ .